# Splitting polygon into three equal parts using NetTopologySuite and C#?

Tags: polygon, c#, algorithm, splitting, nettopologysuite

I have a polygon, I want to split it into three equal parts, I have a scenario as below:

1. User must select a vertex on polygon
2. User must add direction to start split on
3. Based on the node and direction we must select a line segment on polygon
4. ??????

I have no idea how to go farther and then do what to split that line segment. In fact here are some problems:

1. How we can find if the line segment is dividable into for example 3 parts?
   how we van determine the length of each segments on line to divide?
2. If line segment changes its direction what will happen?

Can someone give me some hints how to reach a flowchart on this?

I need the methods to do it,algorithm and things like that, I use .netTopologysuit in C# .net

Comment: What GIS software are you using?  What precisely have you tried to do with that software so far?  As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.

Comment: @PolyGeo I need the algorithms because I want to program it with C# I don't use any application.

Comment: As it stands I think your question is telling us what you want to do without showing precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck. In this case I think showing your code so far would be appropriate.

Comment: @PolyGeo hi, You know in fact I am looking some guide about what I must do, If I can find out the way and steps to do it I can code it but now I have no idea about process and the algorithm to do it and this is why I have asked.

Comment: I can help you splitting a polygon with a line in NTS, but i dont understand the part of splitting it three equal parts. if you choose a vertex and a direction why it whould result in three equal parts?  Maybe if you add some images of what you want to achive we can help you better.

Comment: @cag thanks for your comment. in fact I want an algorithm which gets number of slices, for example 2 and then user selects a vertex on polygon, then we devide polygon into 2 equal parts

Comment: Something like this? http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001t000003wp000000.htm   I have an idea that could work, but the algorithim performance would be poor.

Comment: @cag yes exactly. can you provide your method?maybe there could be some ways to enhance its preformance

Comment: One last question. The parts should have equal width (or height) or equal area? I'm thinking you want equal area polygons, but maybe I'm wrong. Equal size (width or height) would be easier and best performing.